# Application update framework for .net?

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks

I have googled over the internet and read some forums, but I could not find a really good solution to suit my requirements. I am looking for an automatic application update framework for my project.

Which do you think the best application update framework for .net?

Requirements:

- free
- easy to use and integrate with existing .net project
- check/download/install updates automatically from a server
- if it is needed, update also its referenced new dll-s from the server
- if new dll is referenced to the app, should be also downloadad automatically from the server
- if new items (e.g. XML files, language resource files) needed for a new version, also download them

UPDATE:

- installation folder must be changeable by the user (clickonce is not an option)

Comment: Yes, it's called ClickOnce (for example). Please come back with a more-specific question, displaying at least some research effort.

Comment: I have researched a lot, I read pros and contras about all of them an I feel lost, thats why I asked.

Comment: ...and clickonce not a good solution for me, because my users need to specify the location where my sw should be installed and as I know it is not possible to dedictate the destination folder of a clickOnce application.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is it important that the user be allowed to specify the install path?

Comment: This project is complex with several subcomponents and 3rd party things and so on. It is a thing I can not change, so users must have control over installation destination.

Comment: You should be able to downvote grumpy comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out ClickOnce Deployment at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(v=vs.80).aspx

It works really great.  To use it, just open up the project properties in VS and go to the deploy tab.

Comment: I like it but as I know user can not set his installation folder (the folder where he wants to install to). It is very important for me to allow.

Comment: The only way a user can choose an installation location is with Admin priviliges - Do Your Users have Admin priviliges ?

Comment: Thx Yahia. Yes, they are admins. If so, how can they do it? Doe sit have a straightforward way or is it some kind of 'hack'?

Answer (score 5):

check this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/DDayUpdate_Part1.aspx out - it combines ClickOnce (Update machnism) + Windows installer (installation) to make possible what you are asking for...

Another (perhaps better?) option: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/DotNetAutoUpdateClient.aspx

Comment: Thx, I am checking them. Kind from you to help me!